# Trying to use static methods/members

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-members

I've been spoilt with C# coding the last few years and now I'm back onto C++ and finding that I'm having trouble with stuff that is supposed to be simple. I'm using a third party library for gamedev called DarkGDK (any commands which are prefixed with db), however DGDK isn't the problem.

Heres my code:

System.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "DarkGDK.h"

using namespace std;

class System
{
public:
    System();
    ~System();
    void Initialize();

    static void LoadImage(string fileName, string id);
    static int GetImage(string id);

private:
    map<string, int> m_images;
};
```

System.cpp

```
#include "System.h"

System::System()
{
}

System::~System()
{
}

void System::Initialize()
{
    dbSetDisplayMode (1024, 640, 32);
    dbSetWindowTitle ("the Laboratory");
    dbSetWindowPosition(100, 10);

    dbSyncOn         ();
    dbSyncRate       (60);

    dbRandomize(dbTimer());
}

void System::LoadImage(string fileName, string id)
{
    int i = 1;

    while (dbImageExist(i))
    {
        i++;
    }

    dbLoadImage(const_cast<char*>(fileName.c_str()), i, 1);
    m_images[id] = i;
}

int System::GetImage(string id)
{
    return m_images[id];
}
```

The idea here is to have a map which maps strings against integer values, to access images with a string instead of hardcoded values. This class isn't done, so it doesn't handle anything like unloading images. I want to access the image methods without passing an instance of System, so I used static.

Now I get this error:

> blahblah\system.cpp(39) : error C2677:
>   binary '[' : no global operator found
>   which takes type 'std::string' (or
>   there is no acceptable conversion)

If I change the map to static, I get this linker error:

> 1>System.obj : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol "private:
>   static class std::map,class
>   std::allocator >,int,struct
>   std::less,class
>   std::allocator > >,class
>   std::allocator,class
>   std::allocator > const ,int> > >
>   System::m_images"
>   (?m_images@System@@0V?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HU?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@std@@@2@@std@@A)

Can any of you bright chaps help me out?

Comment: Many folks would frown on the use of `using namespace std;` in a header file.  It potentially pollutes the namespace of any modules that include it.  Also, what is the reason for declaring GetImage and LoadImage as static?  You seem to be using them as if they were not.

Comment: Good point about the namespace, thanks. I want the two image related methods static so that I don't have to pass an instance of System to every other class that might want to access an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is a compiler error as you can not access the non-static data members from a static method. `this` pointer is not implictly passed to static methods hence they can not access data members bound to an instance.

In the seconds case, note that `static map<string,int> m_images;` is just a *declaration* of a variable. You need to *define* the static member variable using `map<string, int> System::m_images;` in the source file. This will get rid of the linker error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Naveen, I did indeed realize that the map should be static (not sure why I included that error in my question). The linker error is what got me, defining it in the cpp fixed it right up. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since `m_images` is a non-static member of the class, when you access it from a static member function, you need to specify the object whose `m_images` member you want to use. If there's only supposed to be a single `m_images` object shared by all objects of that class, you want to make it `static` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Static members are always explicitly defined in your program. So it has to be somehow initialised inside System.cpp. If not you get the unresolved external error.

Here's a link to a couple of examples

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.10